# Installing over stove microwave

Tags: microwave-oven

Can I just hardwire microwave and leave 
the connected 2 wires with nuts and the 
gound connected in the cabinet resessed 
space under bottom of cabinet?  And because the electrician who the owner of our building just paid to rewire the entire place, put all the fuse boxes, for each unit together, mine being 2 places over , outside in another persons back yard who has the gate locked, I hope I can do this hot.

Comment: When you say "all the fuse boxes" -- does that include the boxes that protect/feed individual branch circuits in each unit, or is that just the master metering/service complex? Also, is this an apartment you rent, or a condo you own?

Comment: Most modern microwaves are not allowed to be hard-wired. They must have a suitable outlet in the cabinet above.

Comment: @isherwood I just spot-checked a couple of installation manuals for major brands and you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

#### Danger!

Working **hot** is problematic, especially if you are not a pro.

#### Rental

A rental is not the same as owning your home. For the same reason the electrician owner had to **pay someone else** instead of doing it himself, you shouldn't be doing any real electrical work here either.

#### Use As Designed & Tested

Most current models of over-the-stove microwave ovens (I checked a Whirlpool and GE but have no reason to think others are different) are designed to plug in to a standard outlet. Unless specifically authorized by the manufacturer, replacing with a hardwired connection will likely void the warranty and could lead to other problems.

In addition, if you ever need to repair the oven (and I've actually done that successfully on a similar oven after a thermal overload due to user error (a.k.a., food cooked **way** too long and caught on fire...)), you would not have an easy way to shut off all power while you work, because you couldn't simply pull the plug.

#### Proper Installation

No matter who is doing the work, all splices (with certain exceptions) must be inside equipment or junction boxes, not in ordinary cabinets.

Comment: It sounds like there's a serious Code issue afoot as well, that locked gate could very well be a 240.24(B) vio if the keys aren't accessible to all building occupants